# Add optional query parameters to a dynamic path using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to add an optional query parameter to the end of a path, so the URL would look like this: `"/user/1/cars?makeYear=2020"` or `"/user/1/cars"`.  The relevant `Route` is defined as follows. I'm unable to find guidance on how to add an optional query parameter to an existing path. For example, the following doesn't work:

```
<Route path="user" element={<UserScreen />}>
  <Route path=":id/makeYear?" element={<User/>} />
</Route>
```

Here I'd think that `<Route path=":id/makeYear?" element={<User/>} />` will mark `makeYear` as an optional parameter, but no, doesn't work.

I then thought that I'd access the query parameters directly in the component, so given that the URL is `"/user/1/cars?makeYear=2020"`, I can fetch the URL via the `useLocation` api provided by `react-router-dom`. However, the query parameter, this doesn't work either as the query parameter is immediately removed from the URL (I'm guessing by `react-router`).

I'm using `react-router-dom` (6.2.2).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`react-router-dom` doesn't use the queryString for route path matching. Remove the queryString part from the route `path` prop. Access the query params in the component via the [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) hook.

```
<Route path=":id" element={<User/>} />
```

...

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const User = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const makeYear = searchParams.get("makeYear");
  // handle logic based on makeYear

  ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I already tried this. Although I can get the makeYear in my component, the searchParam is immediately removed from the URL. So ```//user/1/cars?makeYear=2020``` changes to ```/user/1/cars```

Comment: @Frosty619 No worries. It sounds like you have some code somewhere stripping it out. Can you provide a more complete code example that does that behavior? See [mcve]? If possible could you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @Frosty619 are you setting your search string when navigating?
the `useNavigate()` hook seems to allow this, according to this article at least:
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/navigate-to-url-query-strings-search-params-react-router

Comment: You were right, there was some other code that was stripping the query param out. Thank you for your help!